# How can I get the number of rows in dynamic query's result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created one dynamic query and it all works well. I execute the query using:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

where @SQLQuery is one dynamic query.

My only question is how can I also return the number of rows present after the execution of this query? I hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `@@rowcount` which will return you the last query effected row count.

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

DECLARE @rowcount int
SET @rowcount = @@rowcount
SELECT @rowcount as NumofRows
```

Answer (score -1):

use the count() function of SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

```
DECLARE @rownum as int
SET @rownum = (SELECT count([column]) from [tablename])
```