# add TotalRow on dynamic TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have functional code which creates dynamic query tsql like:

EventTypeID|CreatedBy |2016-03-01 |2016-03-02  |2016-03-03|...SUM
6          |    2     |     1     |      2     |      0   |... 3
9          |    4     |     0     |      1     |      3   |... 8
...

BUT I want to add last column SUM.

I don't know what is the best practice 'cause I'm new in t-sql.

```
 DECLARE 
 @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @selcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @startdate datetime,
 @enddate datetime,
 @paramdef nvarchar(max)

 SET @startdate = '2013-02-01'
 SET @enddate = '2013-05-10';
 SET @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';


 SELECT 
  @selcols = STUFF((SELECT ','+'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10),  [Date], 120)) + ', 0) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


 SELECT 
 @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

 SET @query = N'SELECT CreatedBy,Name, Surname,EventTypeID,Event, '+ @selcols + '
    from 
    (
        select av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy,emp.Name,emp.Surname,Event,
            convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120) [Date],
            row_number() over(PARTITION BY [date],av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy  order BY av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy ) m

        from AdeccoView av
        left join EventType et on et.EventTypeID = av.EventTypeID
        left join Employee emp on av.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD
        --where datein > @startdate
           -- and datein <= @enddate

    ) x
    pivot 
    (
        max(m)
        for [Date] in ('+@cols+')
    ) p '

 exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startdate, @enddate =@enddate;
```

But I want to add TotalRow (sum).

I've tried to insert into PIVOT section, but I'm not sure that is the way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the number of rows in dynamic query's result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774471/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-rows-in-dynamic-querys-result)

Comment: @har07, I dont think that is for sum of rows on specific query. I need exact values from dynamic columns to be summed. Maybe I need to create #tempTable.